# How do I add values to a an array model in doctrine?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine with Codeigniter, I defined my ratings column as      $this->hasColumn('ratings','array', 1000);. I'm using
         $res = Doctrine::getTable('Resource')->find($resource_id);
  $res->ratings = $rating;
  $res->save();
but only the $rating gets inserted, overwriting the last value, I want to store the ratings as an array, ex: 1,5,4,2,3,5,1 etc.. How do I add/retrieve values from a table column defined as array with Doctrine? (I'm using mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it, I'll post the code below maybe someone will find it usefull

```
    public function add_rating() {
        $rating = (int) $this->uri->segment(3);
        $resource_id = (int) $this->uri->segment(4);
        if((is_numeric($rating)) && ($rating > 0) && ($rating <= 5)) {
            $res = Doctrine::getTable('Resource')->find($resource_id);
            $ratings = $res->ratings;
            $ratings[] = $rating;
            $res->ratings = $ratings;
//          echo '<pre>';
//          echo  print_r($ratings);
            $res->save();
        }
        redirect('/home/show/' . $resource_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but as the Doctrine "array" type is equivalent to MySQL TEXT type, in PHP I would use implode() and explode() functions to create a comma-separated string of values that is stored as a text string. MySQL VARCHAR might be more suitable for your needs. The Doctrine equivalent for this is "string".

Hope that helps.